# could not initialize proxy - no Session - Production server only?

Tags: java, hibernate

I know this issue has been beat to death and I have read up on all the various solutions such as adjusting the lazy fetching.  The issue is that this application has been running for a couple years now and just recently started having this issue.

The strange part is this application works fine on my local dev machine as well as our testing server.  Once I deploy this into our production site I get the error.  So I don't believe its an application problem, it has to be something with the server, maybe some sort of tomcat configuration that might somehow be different?

The setups are the same between all 3 servers with versions of tomcat/mysql/java.  Does anyone have ideas on what I can look at?

For what its working im running hibernate 3.5.3, Spring 3.02, Struts 2.2.1, Tomcat 6.0.24, Mysql 5.1.67 on a RHEL 6.3 Server

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would explore 2 parallel paths to figuring out the answer.

One is, try to troubleshoot the problem itself.  Crank up your log levels to DEBUG and see if that illuminates anything.  Are you able to successfully fetch a simple object, and only complex objects (those that have a sub-object) cause a problem? etc.  It may have to do with the data source / connection pool, which often has a different setup in production.

The 2nd approach is, figure out what has changed.  If this problem just started happening, then something must have changed.  Have you upgraded a library, changed versions of Tomcat, changed the OS, etc.

Related to this 2nd approach is figuring out what is different between your development/test environment and production.  They can't be "the same" in every way if the problem occurs reliably in production but not the others.  If you have a version of "production" that you can tinker with, without screwing with active users, then you can experiment with changes and see if you can isolate the specific thing that causes the problem to appear.